# Golang using ServeFile and HandleFunc

Tags: go

This is a cut-down version of some other code which I'm struggling to work

The go code..

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
    )
    
    func main() {
    
        http.HandleFunc("/test", testPageHandler)
    
        log.Print("Listening on :8080...")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    
    func testPageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./test.html")
    }
```

The HTML is also very basic

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/main.css">
    <script src="static/javascript/sayHello.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<br>
<div id="helloWorld"></div>
<script>showText()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The css

```
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

The js

```
function showText()
{
    document.getElementById("helloWorld").innerHTML="<p> I'm here </p>";
}
```

The folder layout..

The browser console shows..

[image]

The folder layout

[image]

I kinda get that the error is a 404 but for the life of me I can't understand why the css and js files aren't found. Opening the html file from the IDE renders it fine, so guess there is some functionality in the Go HTTP server I'm missing.

Although there may be other workarounds I'm trying to understand why the HandeFunc and ServeFile aren't working

Comment: Your program is only serving the `/test` endpoint, and the registered handler for that endpoint serves only a single html file. There is no handler in your code that handles requests coming to, for example, `/static/css/main.css`. Serving a file that has hyperlinks in its HTML will not automagically configure your Go program to also serve the files referenced by those hyperlinks. The internet, including SO itself, is replete with examples of how to serve static files with Go.

Comment: Hey @mkopriva, thanks for the quick reply. What you makes perfect sense. Once I added a http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))) the CSS and js came alive.